# How can i convince my CTO that opening our code can be very good for the company?

Tags: open-source

I am trying to convince him in an attempt to produce better code by separating concerns, isolate logic and following best practices.

He wants to produce readable/shareable code but is not entirely convinced that opening it is a good idea.

What other arguments can i use?

Comment: "opening"? As in, going open source? Going open source won't solve you anything at all if your team is unable to keep it up with the skills required by the project. I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: One of our problems is logic dispersion. Now Imagine you want to produce a front end component. If you plan to open source it you will want to write with detachable business logic.

Comment: You'll want to write it with detachable business logic even if you don't open source it (I mean, best practices shouldn't be driven by whether the project is open source or not... if it takes the threat of others seeing the code to make your team do well with it, maybe there's a more fundamental issue that should be addressed?)

Comment: Open source is a license not a requirement. I can open source my mothers recipe for lasagna. Not much in the way of business logic there (just layers, and indirection when I lose my grip on the fork) but the sauce is incredible.

Comment: I guess that i should continue with this argument then. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I think you need to stop conflating two separate issues.  Why do you think going open source will help with anything at all?

Comment: This makes as much sense as buying an expensive Gym membership because paying a lot of money will make us feel like we have to work out everyday. Great business model.  If you own the Gym.

Comment: see [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Answer (score 5):

Well, why do *you* think opening is a good idea, in the first place?

Open Source has nothing to do with code quality - it is just a license, nothing else.

Going open source definitely *wont* help you to increase your code quality - you need a good team with good skills and good management to accomplish that. You can very easily find several open source pieces of garbage for every shinning gem out there on the dark depths of GitHub.

Unless you are thinking about cooperative effort to build a open-source project, like what is done with several flavors of *nix systems, going open source won't help you at all.

If you *are* thinking about getting free, cooperative effort from your community, you better have a very good product already. We as developers love to build stuff and to solve problems, but we *won't* code for *anyone* for free unless we have a very damn good reason.

Like virtual internet cookie points. We *love* virtual internet cookie points.

Nevertheless, without knowing *why* you think going open will help you, we can't give you any answer different from "it won't" with any semblance of accuracy.

Comment: Not to mention that managing an active open source project is an art in and of its own...